# Почему обнуляется счетчик переменной в цикле while? И вообще ведет себя по-разному, в зависимости от места объявления переменной

Tags: c, циклы

Выполняю задание по cs50, нужно восстановить все изображения jpg с карты памяти, которые переписаны с карты в файл card.raw.
Ниже рабочий код. Но если я объявляю переменную count ниже массива т.е. вот так

```
BYTE jpgBlock[512];

int count = 0;
```

программа перестает работать корректно. А именно в цикле while после первого прохода внутреннего цикла (когда найдена сигнатура jpg и 1-е изображение записано до конца - т.е. до момента пока не встретиться сигнатура след. картинки) в конце счетчик увеличивается и count равен 1, заходя на 2 проход после выполнения строки

```
sprintf(outfile, "%03d.jpg", count);
```

счетчик обнуляется, т.е. count становится равным 0. Почему так? Почему это зависит от того выше или ниже count объявлен относительно BYTE jpgBlock[512];

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cs50.h>

typedef uint8_t BYTE;

int main(void)
{
    FILE *inptr = fopen("card.raw", "r");
    if (inptr == NULL)
    {
         return 1;
    }

    int count = 0;

    BYTE jpgBlock[512];     

    while(1)
    {
        char outfile[7];

        sprintf(outfile, "%03d.jpg", count);

        FILE *outptr = fopen(outfile, "w");
        if(outptr == NULL)
        {
              return 2;
        }

        for (int countFirstBlock = 0; fread(jpgBlock, sizeof(jpgBlock), 1, inptr) == 1; )
        {
              if(jpgBlock[0] == 255 && jpgBlock[1] == 216 && jpgBlock[2] == 255)
              {
                  ++countFirstBlock;
              }


              if(countFirstBlock == 1)
              {
                  fwrite(jpgBlock, sizeof(jpgBlock), 1, outptr);
              }

              if(countFirstBlock == 2)
              {
                  break;
              }      
        }

        fclose(outptr);

        if(feof(inptr))
        {
            break;
        }

        fseek(inptr, -(int)sizeof(jpgBlock), SEEK_CUR);

        ++count;
    }

    fclose(inptr);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Дело в том, что ваш

```
sprintf(outfile, "%03d.jpg", count);
```

вылетает за пределы буфера

```
char outfile[7];
```

и в результате порождает неопределенное поведение. Что, в частности, запросто может выражаться в затирании ваш располагающийся по соседству в памяти `count`.

Ваш `sprintf` формирует строку длиной как минимум 7 символов. Для хранения такой строки нужен будет буфер размера 8, так как строка должна еще включать нулевой символ-терминатор. А вы выделили только буфер размера 7. Вылет за пределы гарантирован.

Comment: А вы попробуйте! Я почти уверен, что это не проблема (на стеке у 32-битных платформ всё выровнено).

Comment: @0andriy: Вы шутите? О том, что это проблема споров быть не может. Запись 8 символов в массив длины 7 - это проблема, "проблемность" которой обсуждаться здесь не будет. Все с этим согласны. А уж "пробовать" можно сколько угодно на разных плафтормах - это не более чем бесполезное экспериментрование с неопределенным поведением.

Comment: Скажем так, размер потребного буфера зависит от значения `count`. При достаточно больших значениях, результат гарантированно вылезет за пределы 7 символов (даже с учетом возможного выравнивания). При count=100 нужно 8 символов, при 1000 - уже 9. Тут UB чистой воды, результат непредсказуем

Comment: @andy.37: Благодаря `03` в формате результат преобразования всегда гарантированно вылезает за пределы массива.

Comment: @AnT, ну да, я на 03 внимания не обратил.

Comment: @AnT, я не готов спорить, пока не увижу код, который **сгенерирован** компилятором. По виду это конечно же UB, а по факту может и не быть.

Comment: @0andriy это UB по факту, так как поведение зависит от компилятора (в частности).

Comment: Ещё раз. По факту всё зависит от **реального, исполняемого** кода. Дальше можно не продолжать, я соглашусь, что ошибка на 99.99% в этом, но посмотреть кодогенерацию тоже интересно бывает.

Comment: да, заработало после увеличения значения массива char[], спасибо!

Comment: @0andriy еще раз, если поведение программы зависит от того, какой *реальный исполняемый код * сгенерирует компилятор, то именно это и называется UB.

Comment: @0andriy: Ранняя детекция UB современными компиляторами и влияние ее на генерируемый код - факт в современных компиляторах реальный и распространенный, сколько бы жалобно ни пищали на эту тему разнообразные "c0ol hack0rz". А заниматься гаданием о том, попадает ли данный пример UB в эту категорию (то есть является ли он "по факту" или "по виду") - бессмысленная и бесполезная трата времени.

Comment: С этим никто и не спорит. Мы разное вкладываем в "по факту".