# fwrite чудит или я, чего-то не понимаю?

Tags: c

Вопрос собственно такой, читается поток байт, проверяется что это jpeg 
при помощи: `buffer[0]==0xff && buffer[1]==0xd8 && buffer[2]==0xff && (buffer[3] & 0xf0) == 0xe0`
Все отлично определяется, но затем происходит, какая то магия, при записи в новый файл buffer[0] превращается из 0xff в 0x00, как такое может быть, там же идет указатель но область памяти, что не так то :( При это все остальное остается идентичным.

Как видно из кода я влепил такую строку `buffer[0]=0xff;` что б это чудо выправить, но это же костыль!!!

```
    FILE *otpf;
    uint8_t buffer[BLOCKSIZE];
    char filename[7];
    int count = 0;
    int startJpeg = 0;

    while(fread(&buffer, 1, sizeof(buffer), inptr)==sizeof(buffer)) {
        if(buffer[0]==0xff && buffer[1]==0xd8 && buffer[2]==0xff && (buffer[3] & 0xf0) == 0xe0 ) {
            startJpeg = 1;
            if(otpf!=NULL) {
                fclose(otpf);
            }

            sprintf(filename,"%03i.jpg",count++);
            otpf = fopen(filename,"w");
            buffer[0]=0xff;
            fwrite(&buffer,1,sizeof(buffer),otpf);
        } else{
            if(startJpeg == 1) 
                fwrite(&buffer,1,sizeof(buffer), otpf);
        }

    }

    if(otpf!= NULL) {
        fclose(otpf);    
    }

    fclose(inptr);
```

Comment: Покажите код - не только этот. Потому что причина может быть в чем угодно. Да хоть `filename`короткий, лежит рябом с `buffer`, и перезаписывается завершающий нолик в `buffer[0]` - чем не версия? :) Кстати, вы проверяли - это именно `buffer[0]` затирается? Проблема не в записи, например?...

Comment: А как объявляется `buffer`? Почему файл открывается на запись без `"b"`?

Comment: @Harry вот весь код

Comment: Практически эта же самая ошибка, именно в такой форме, уже здесь была http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/619493/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B2-%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B5-while-%D0%98-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%82-%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B1%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%BE . Причем именно с `jpg`, длиной массива `7` и форматом  `03`. Это откуда-то копируют что ли?

Comment: @AnT Ну вот... Ничто не ново под Луной :) Даже ошибки...

Comment: Ну так задача с курса cs50 :) Самое обидно все сделал быстро а с этим час просидел

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Произошло чудо! Учитесь, пока я жив! :)

Мой комментарий:

*Покажите код - не только этот. Потому что причина может быть в чем угодно. Да хоть `filename` короткий, лежит рядом с `buffer`, и перезаписывается завершающий нолик в `buffer[0]` - чем не версия? :)*

**Именно это и происходит! `filename` у вас 7 байт, а нужно-то 8! Вот вы и затираете `buffer[0]`!**

Нет, это надо оставить потомкам :) Такая телепатия - это редко бывает...

Comment: ААА Аааа ааа, вы правы :( блин учиться считать надо я про \0 забыл получается ?

Comment: Ну, вообще-то, да :(

Comment: Круто! А есть ли гарантия что значение `count` будет не больше 999?

Comment: В этой задаче да

Comment: Да, здорово. А вот с gcc такого бы не произошло, он массивы длиннее одного байта на 16 выравнивает.