# Почему, если в названии файла jpeg нет `\0` программа так себя ведет?

Tags: c, jpeg, cs50

По заданию в cs50 нужно было вынуть jpeg-и из файла RAW и записать каждую картинку в отдельный файл. Этот файл RAW имитировал только что стертую флешку. Я завела строку `char image_name[7]` и забыла поставить `\0`( формат названия `XXX.jpeg`) . В результате, при ПОЛНОСТЬЮ работающей остальной логике программы она находила только первую и последнюю картинку и завершалась. Как только я добавила `\0` программа нашла все 50 картинок. Очень хочется понять логику машины. Что такое происходило, что приводило к такому результату?

Как только моя программа находила начало jpeg-а в исходном файле(.RAW), она закрывала предыдущий файл для записи (если он был) и создавала новый файл, как раз в этом моменте использовалась строка `image_name`:

```
//create a name for an image
  sprintf(image_name, "%03i.jpg", imgn);
//create and open an output file for writing an image
  imgptr = fopen(image_name, "w");
```

`imgn` = счетчик картинок. Затем программа записывала jpg, пока не находила следующий jpg в исходном файле.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы неправильное интерпретируете происходящее. `sprintf` всегда сам добавляет `\0` в конец строки. Самостоятельно туда никакого `\0` добавлять не нужно.

Однако вашего `char image_name[7];` совершенно не достаточно для хранения вашего имени файла. Ваше имя файла требует буфера размера 8 как минимум, а вы предоставили только 7. Происходит вылет за пределы буфера, после которого поведение вашего кода не определено.

Ваши попытки куда-то добавлять какой-то `\0` - это не более чем отчаянные попытки заставить уже "мертвую" программу подавать какие-то признаки жизни. Не надо заниматься подобной ерундой. Объявите буфер правильного размера и никакой `\0` никуда добавлять не надо будет - он сам добавится.

P.S. Что характерно, вот это `"%03i.jpg"` с буфером размера 7 постоянно гуляет из вопроса в вопрос:

[fwrite чудит или я, чего-то не понимаю?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/632890/fwrite-%D1%87%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%8F-%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%8E)

[Почему обнуляется счетчик переменной в цикле while? И вообще ведет себя по-разному, в зависимости от места объявления переменной](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/619493/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B2-%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B5-while-%D0%98-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%82-%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B1%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%BE)

Это из "учебника" какого-то что-ли копируют?

Comment: Это из одного из заданий к гарвардскому онлайн курсу для начинашек Computer Science 50 (CS50).  Инфа про sprintf полезная. Спасибо.

Comment: @Curious Mind: То, что *задание* из CS50 я понимаю. Вопрос о том, откуда взялось `"%03i.jpg"` в буфер размера 7. Это тоже из CS50? И если да, то где именно это там можно найти?

Comment: [ссылка](https://docs.cs50.net/2018/x/psets/4/recover/recover.html) `"%03i.jpg"` упоминается в видео с разбором задания где-то на 5:05. Размер массива там не указан, просто многие делают такую ошибку.

Answer (score 1):

У вас имя из 8 символов (`XXX.jpeg`) запихивалось в массив из 7, т.е. получалось классическое UB (неопределенное поведение). Грубо говоря, происходить могло вообще что угодно. Кстати, судя по коду у вас в 7 символов таки писалось 7 символов + нулевой (`sprintf` его пишет), но сути дела это не меняет. В лучшем случае, чтоб понять, что там происходило - надо копаться в генерируемом коде, потому что каждый компилятор делает по-своему (и даже при разных ключах компиляции - по-разному). Так что вряд ли вам кто-то сможет сказать, почему программа вела себя именно так а не, скажем, просто валилась...